# Regression analysis method when data is linked to a normalised time... and only hold a relationship for some of it

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, normalization, stepwise-regression

Stats novice... Please be patient, but I would really appreciate some help. I am using SPSS.

I have made some kinematic measurements of a closed chain, repeated movement.

I have a large number of data sets, all normalised in the same way, so each set has 101 rows representing 0-100% of an averaged movement. As its cyclical, 0% is the start, the movement is completed and 100% represents the end, which in time and position is the same as 0%.

I want to investigate the relationships between some measurements (my independents) and others (dependants), and can perform multiple linear regression analysis for discrete points (eg the measurements at 0%, measurements at 10%, measurements at 20%). This is a far as previous work has gone.

However I also want to investigate the relationships for all the normalised % range... But some of the data only has a relationship for some of the time (eg one pair of variables X & Y might display a decent correlation from 0 to 22%, but no relationship in the rest of the rows of data. In this case the two measurements are related, but not for all of the normalised % points, so overall correlation is lost and linear regression doesnt work).

I am confused as the data is normalised and not explicitly time based, and I want to investigate relationships, but some measurements (I think) are only linked for some of the % normalised range.... but I dont know when...

A) What methods should I use to identify the relationships for all the normalised % rows? Ie going further than just cheating and doing linear multiple regression for just a few discrete points.

B) How to see if there are relationships within the range of % values? And ideally identify these ranges?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If there are recurring patterns in these relationships, e.g., in periods 10-25 and again from 60-80 (this is totally made up), this sounds like a kind of "seasonality" in the cycles of your data. One way to deal with that in your model is to add dummy variables that are zero in the off-cycle periods and 1 when the pattern occurs.  This approach will adjust the intercept as well as the other parameters in the model. In their absence, the other parameters will be biased.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there might perhaps be a step method that looked within the data for me, but I think your idea for looking at discrete ranges might be the best option.

However, everyone out there, I would alwaus appreciate any more inputs on this !